# Ubuntu 9 & 10 ignore .xinitrc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu 9.x, 10.x, the .xinitrc file is apparently not used. So, where do you put your xinit stuff?

Note: asking this here, answering it myself, in light of https://serverfault.com/questions/87156/ubuntu-karmic-ignores-xinitrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .xsession instead. You can opt to symlink .xinitrc to .xsession if you like:

```
ln -s .xinitrc .xsession
```

That said, I'm still not really sure *why* this is the case. More info on the way Ubuntu launches X would be helpful here.

Comment: as the link you post in the question describes, Ubuntu launches X via GDM.